# Optimize this query further? - indexed but still slow

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a query below that joins 4 tables. I have added indexes and the explain output looks good with indexes used (see below).

Can I optimize the query further?

The modelXml is rather big on some records.For a big project where I get back 22 records, each with approximately 2.5 - 3MB of modelXml data, the query is taking long (total of 69MB of data returned). 
I suspect this is the issue but not sure how to deal with it.
I was reading on adjusting internal mysql variables e.g key_buffer_size and table_cache.  Would any of this help?

key_buffer_size is currently set at 8384512 (~8MB) and table_cache at 64
What should I increase it to? 
What other variables should I be looking at to manage to speed up return of such big data?

Any other suggestions are welcome. I am a novice to mysql but really trying to get better.

```
SELECT `m`.`modelId`, `m`.`modelTypeId`, `m`.`modelXml`, `m`.`xmlSize`, `m`.`createdById`, `m`.`creationDate`, `m`.`modifiedDate`, `u`.`firstName`, `u`.`lastName` FROM `models_1` AS `m` 
INNER JOIN `modelFolderAssociations_1` AS `mfa` ON m.modelId = mfa.modelIOId 
INNER JOIN `modelFolders_1` AS `mf` ON mfa.folderId = mf.folderId 
INNER JOIN `users_1` AS `u` ON m.createdById = u.userId 
WHERE (m.projectId = 2) AND (mfa.folderId = 5) AND (mfa.modelIOType = 2) AND (m.modelTypeId = 2)

CREATE TABLE `models` (
 `modelId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `groupId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `projectId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `createdById` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `modelTypeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `modelXml` longtext,
 `modelSpecXml` longtext NOT NULL,
 `xmlSize` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
 `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modifiedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`modelId`,`customerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 


CREATE TABLE `modelFolders` (
     `folderId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `groupId` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `projectId` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `parentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `folderName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
     `folderType` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `editable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
     `nextDefaultNameNumber` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
     `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
     `modifiedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`folderId`,`customerId`),
     KEY `parentId` (`parentId`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `modelFolderAssociations` (
 `associationId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `folderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `projectId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `modelIOId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `modelIOType` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
 `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modifiedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`associationId`,`customerId`),
 KEY `folderId` (`folderId`,`modelIOType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `userId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `userName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `firstName` varchar(50) default NULL,
 `lastName` varchar(50) default NULL,
 `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modifiedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`userId`,`customerId`),
 UNIQUE KEY `userName` (`userName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Explain output**

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                                               | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | modelFolders            | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 8       | const,const                                       |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | modelFolderAssociations | ref    | folderId      | folderId | 5       | const,const                                       |   22 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | models                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 8       | xa_system.modelFolderAssociations.modelIOId,const |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 8       | xa_system.models.createdById,const                |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Is php running on the same box as mysql? As you mentioned 69MB is quite a big chunk to digest if it flies over the network especially if when you'll be adding some load. My feeling is that you should look at other solutions than just tuning SQL + DB Server. Willing to explore other avenues?

Comment: @Derick - yes php is running on the same box as mysql. This test in on my sandbox. What other solutions do you have in mind?

Comment: I'll not post an answer since you wanted query tuning. But, the first thing I would look at is if I really need 3MB per entity? 69MB just for a "business transaction"? I would try to break it up and even dare denormalization. For example a 3MB CustomerOrder or CutomerOrderMetaData entity looks weird... but it depends on your domain or what you use the records for.

Comment: @Derick - yes, we might have to break things up.

Comment: No one commented on the server variables. Is there anything there that I can do to improve things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having large text columns, like those you're using to store XML I presume, can hurt performance regardless of how well your indexes are structured.

It can be better in these cases to move the text columns to a separate table, indexed by string length which you're already storing and CRC32.

```
CREATE TABLE MODEL_XML (
 xmlId INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 xmlSize BIGINT(20) NOT NULL default '0',
 crc32 INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 xmlData LONGTEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY (xmlId),
 UNIQUE KEY (xmlSize, crc32)
)
```

Then the width of your columns on the table with your important indices becomes constant.

ex.

```
modelXmlId INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL
specXmlId INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL
```

It also has the benefit of being more space-efficient for redundant text (empty strings, etc) since they would all share one xmlId and thus one row in the DB.

Comment: This would also mean adding another table to join. I already have a 'reports' table that holds mostly XML. I will experiment with that.

Comment: The inserts also get a bit more complex since you have to compute CRC32, but in my experience having any kind of text column on the same table as the index you're using for the where clause can degrade performance.

Comment: Though your answer did not solve my problem fully, it gave me an insight - therefore I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should index your foreign keys, this will really help with your joins:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_MODELS_CUSTID
on models (customerId)

CREATE INDEX IDX_FLDR_ASSOC_MODELIO
modelFolderAssociations(modelIOId)


CREATE INDEX IDX_FLDR_ASSOC_FLDRID
modelFolderAssociations(folderId)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I had wondered about use of foreign keys vs just indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Test your query after taking off the modelXml column from the SELECT clause.

If the speed is then significantly better, then the slowness comes from the volume off data to transfer, not the query itself.

Comment: I have projects with small data whereby the modelXML is some kb and that is fast (could be faster I am sure).

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes don't always match the queries and joins.  If all of the columns in your WHERE and JOIN clauses are not in the index, you're forcing mysql to look at the underlying row, which will kill your performance, especially since your model rows are so wide.

For "modelFolderAssociations", you made the correct composite key for the where clause, but you should include modelIOId for the join to model.

For "models", you'd want a composite index on (modelId, projectId, modelTypeId, createdById ) to cover the incoming link from mfa, the two items in the where clause, and the outbound link to users.

For "modelFolders" and "users", you have the incoming join covered in your primary keys.

The engine is only going to use one index, so adding extra index single indexes (as Mike suggested) won't be as good.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I will try the composite indexes you suggested. I was still trying to read up on the effect of adding foreign keys as mike suggested but your explanation makes sense. Question but won't such a long index add overhead? I guess I will answer when I add the composite index but I was just asking generally

Comment: an UPDATE. I added the composite key suggested on mfa and on models but they do not make a difference. The optimizer still chooses the same keys it had choosen earlier.

Comment: Yes, longer indexes will add overhead for inserts/updates, but fortunately, these are all ints, which shouldn't be too bad.